# Food stain on polycrylic cabinet

Tags: finishing, clean-up

I just finished painting my cabinets white, and to finish it off I put three coats of polycrylic on top to make them more durable. I placed the cabinet doors back on yesterday. Today, while making a berry smoothie for breakfast I splattered some on the cabinet door, but didn't notice it for a couple of hours. When I did, I went to wipe it off, but it left a stain on my white door that will not come off.

Three questions:

1. Is there anything I can do that will remove the stain without harming the polycrylic?
2. How did this happen? I figured polycrylic would encourage stains to wipe right off.
3. What should I do now to make sure future messes won't stain the cabinets?

Comment: 1, try bleach. 2, berry juice contains natural dyes and dyes are very good at penetrating. 3, be vigilant? The finish hasn't cured yet (that'll probably take a couple of weeks, possibly longer) and you may see a marked improvement in various aspects of durability after it has fully cured, But Polycrylic isn't the best finish anyway..... many waterbased finishes aren't that great but Minwax stuff generally is often near the bottom quality-wise in any given class.

Comment: Did you use matt, satin or gloss BTW?

Comment: Try a UV light, or dismounting the door and placing it in sunlight.  May take a couple of weeks.  Try other bleaches -- oxalic acid, perchlorate...